# How can I edit a Django project in Ubuntu EC2 after it was cloned from Git?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I created an Ubuntu EC2 instance and uploaded my Django project (formerly uploaded to git) by following the steps used in the YouTube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjrfUO91wfc). The Django project worked fine on my local computer using the 127.0.0.1:8000 url & port. I want to keep developing it on the Ubuntu EC2 instance, but after adding a new url, view, and template, the project breaks. As a test, I copied edits and new files back to my local computer and tried to recreate the problem, but it worked fine.  Is it not possible to edit Django projects on Ubuntu EC2? Will I have to solely develop in Git and re-push to EC2 every time I want to updated my website?
Thanks!

Comment: Developing code directly on EC2 is not the best approach. You should develop off-instance and build automation that allows you to deploy changes to EC2. That said, no you don't have to do it this way (or using git) so you should investigate why the changes you made broke things.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to restart gunicorn:

`systemctl restart gunicorn`

you only need to restart nginx when you change any related nginx configurations

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out - it is necessary to restart nginx and gunicorn after making changes with the following code:

```
sudo service nginx restart; sudo service gunicorn restart
```